# I want full code filter posts with custom taxonamy in worder

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to filter my posts under custom taxonomy. When I click on a particular taxonomy it will shows the posts related to that taxonomy. I click on a particular taxonomy its permalink changes but posts does not changed.

[image: web image]